# Where do I find the latest phone update (Mango RTM) for developers?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I did a soft reset of my WP7 phone, unlocked it for development and updated it with Zune, but I got the version 7.0.739, not 7.1! This means that I cannot deploy my Mango testing apps into the phone :(

Where can I find the latest update for developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not Find the update as you have not been given an Invitation to the Microsofts Connect website, you should seek out another Developer's Mango Beta 2 files and install those on your machine, register your phone and unlock the device using the Windows Phone Tools you get with the installer, the Zune software that is in Beta points to another Location for Updates specifically to developers registered before Mid June if I am not mistaken, those all got an invite to download using the Microsoft Connect website,

This is the only way you will be able to get Mango I am afraid, go and look on the XDA Forums as the RTM Version they have is Carrier Exempt it just flashes straight on to your phone,

Comment: You're right. I asked for the files to another developer and got it working :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the RTM of mango will not be released to developers. The RTM will only be available through your carrier.

The beta version (7712) is available through the apphub/connect.

Comment: @alfonso you'll be prompted on your phone and in Zune (when connected) when it's available for your device. This won't be yet though as it's currently only available in Japan.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a registered developer on the App Hub (create.msdn.com) to get access to a Mango phone update. You can of course use the emulator for development of Mango apps however.

Comment: You will need to go to connect.microsoft.com and login with your developer account to get access to the Mango build. The instructions are on create.msdn.com